# What is the minimal polynomial of $x_1$ + $x_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Minimal polynomial for a vector x relative to a matrix $A$ is defined as the least degree polynomial P(t) such that:
$P(A)x = 0$. Suppose we have $P_1(t)$ is the minimal polynomial of $x_1$ relative to A and $P_2(t)$ is the minimal polynomial of $x_2$ relative to A. What is the minimal polynomial for $x_1 + x_2$?

I was thinking that the polynomial $Q(t)$ such that $Q(A)(x_1+x_2) = 0$ must be $lcm(P_1, P_2)$ but I can't prove it. Does it have to be the case that $Q(A)x_1 = 0$ and $Q(A)x_2 = 0$ if we want $Q(A)(x_1+x_2) = 0$?

Comment: What if $x_2=-x_1$ ?

Comment: point taken. what if GCD($P_1$, $P_2$) = 1?